# Excel: Insert blank row if non consecutive date

Tags: vba, excel

We have a process at work that runs every 31 hours and would like to have a column in an Excel 2010 spreadsheet that reflects the time and dates the process is due to run each day over the coming year e.g.

start date (Cell:A1):

10/31/2016 1:00

11/1/2016 8:00

11/2/2016 15:00

11/3/2016 22:00

11/5/2016 5:00

11/6/2016 12:00

11/7/2016 19:00

11/9/2016 2:00

11/10/2016 9:00

11/11/2016 16:00

11/12/2016 23:00

11/14/2016 6:00

I am currently using the formula: A2 =A1  +  (31/24) to populate the dates and times in the column which appears to work ok. I need to insert a blank row between days that are not consecutive (in order to highlight that fact, to make it easier for the operators to read and not instigate the process at the wrong time!) which is where the difficulty lies. I am assuming that I will need a separate VBA function to step through each cell and compare the day date (ignoring time value.) in the previous cell, if day date is greater than 1 (as in not the following day.) insert a blank row.

I am looking for a solution to the following scenario but am struggling to get my head round it and would appreciate any guidance/ help anyone is able to provide.

Many thanks

Comment: Just to make sure I understood your question: In your example above you would like to have an empty row between 11/3 and 11/5 because 11/4 is missing?

Comment: Can you use a helper column that has each calendar day and another column that has the actual process due date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need a VBA Function for that, it can be accomplished with the function

```
A3 = IF(A2="",A1+31/24, IF(INT(A2+31/24)=INT(A2)+1,A2+31/24,""))
```

*For that to work, you will have to populate cells `A1` and `A2` manually, though.

You can use the `INT()` function to get the date part of a `DateTime` field, so it becomes simple to check if adding 31 hours will leave a 1 day gap in the sequence by checking `INT(A2+31/24) = INT(A2)+1`.

So, to explain the function, the part

```
IF(INT(A2+31/24)=INT(A2)+1,A2+31/24,"")
```

will check if the days are consecutive, and if so, it will fill the `DateTime`. If not, it will leave it blank.

The outer `IF` checks if the cell above is blank. If it is, the function will use the one above that.